# XML to JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, json

I have the following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <bpmn2:process id="process_1" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn2:subProcess id="SubProcess_1" name="Sub Process 1">
      <bpmn2:task id="Task_4" name="Task 4">
      </bpmn2:task>
      <bpmn2:task id="Task_2" name="Task 2">
      </bpmn2:task>
      <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_2" name="">
      </bpmn2:startEvent>
      <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_2" name="">
      </bpmn2:endEvent>
      <bpmn2:task id="Task_3" name="Task 3">
      </bpmn2:task>
    </bpmn2:subProcess>
    <bpmn2:subProcess id="SubProcess_2" name="Sub Process 2">
      <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_3" name="">
      </bpmn2:startEvent>
      <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_3" name="">
      </bpmn2:endEvent>
      <bpmn2:task id="Task_5" name="Task 5">
      </bpmn2:task>
    </bpmn2:subProcess>
  </bpmn2:process>
```

I want to generate the Json String for this xml. 
I have already writen the code for generating the Json String if inside the `<bpmn2:process> </bpmn2:process>` tags there is only one `<bpmn2:subProcess>` node, but now I don't know how to do when I have more than one **bpmn2:subProcess** node. 
My code so far is :

```
Node nodeSubProcess = getNode("bpmn2:subProcess");
jw = new JSONStringer();

    jw.object(); //create a new object for bpmn2:subProcess


            generateChildNodesDefinitions(nodeSubProcess);

            jw.endObject(); // close the object for bpmn2:subProcess

            System.out.println(jw.toString());
```

And inside the **generateChildNodesDefinitions(nodeSubProcess)** method I have the code how I want to generate the Json string for my xml file, when  I have only one subProcess node:

```
public static void generateChildNodesDefinitions(Node node) throws JSONException
    {
if (node != null && node.hasChildNodes())
        {
            jw.key("nodes").array();

            NodeList childnodelist = node.getChildNodes();

            for (int k = 0; k < childnodelist.getLength(); k++)
            {
                Node childn = childnodelist.item(k);

                if (childn.hasAttributes())
                {


                    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) jsonValues.get(childn.getNodeName()); //where jsonValues is e Map where I have defined some new values I want to generate for each node I have inside pbmn2:subProcess node
                    // get attributes for each childnode

                    NamedNodeMap nnmchildnodes = childn.getAttributes();
                    // for each node create a JsonObject

                    jw.object();

                    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty())
                    {
                       jw.key("stencil").value(list.get(0)); 

                        jw.key("category").value("NODE");

                        if (list.get(1) != null)
                        {
                            jw.key(list.get(1)).value(list.get(2));
                        }

                    }

                    jw.endObject();


                }

            }

            jw.endArray();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [JSON in Java API](http://www.json.org/java/). It does all of the hard work for you.

```
public String xmlToJSON(String xmlString){

    try {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        String jsonString = xmlJSONObj.toString(4);
    }catch (JSONException je){
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) both for parsing the xml and for writing the json back. Especially if you plan to process your data in java. If you only want a conversion, Jackson might be overkill. If you want your conversion to work in both ways, Jackson might provide an elegant solution. Jackson is meant for json (de-)serialization and can be [extended to be used with xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml).

Parsing your xml into your data classes is as simple as:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
YourRootClass yourRootObject = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, YourRootClass.class);
```

Writing your json back is as simple as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(fileOutput, yourRootObject);
```

You need to annotate your data classes in order for Jackson to work.

- [Jackson Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)
- [Additional XML Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations)